# Merging two tables in sql using unions

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I want to show the data from 2 tables, for that i am using union, which is not working.

```
 SELECT   
  CA.ContactAddressId,  
  CA.CompanyName AS CompanyName,  
  CA.ContactPerson AS ContactPerson,  
  CA.Address1 AS Street,  
  ISNULL(CA.Address2,'') AS Street2,  
  CA.City,  
  CA.[State] AS [State],  
  CA.Country AS CountryCode,  
  CASE  
   WHEN CA.Country = 1 THEN 'USA'  
   WHEN CA.Country = 2 THEN 'CANADA'  
   WHEN CA.Country = 4 THEN 'MEXICO'  
  END AS Country,  
  CA.ZipCode,  
  CA.WorkPhone AS Phone,  
  ISNULL(CA.Fax,'') AS Fax,  
  CA.Email AS [Email],  
  CA.AddressType,  
  CA.AddressCode,  
  CADS.PickupReadyTime AS PickupReadyTime,  
  CADS.PickupCloseTime AS PickupCloseTime,  
  CADS.DeliveryReadyTime AS DeliveryOpeningTime,  
  CADS.DeliveryCloseTime AS DeliveryClosingTime,  
  CAST(ISNULL(CAD.ContactAddressId,0) as bit) IsDefault,  
  CADS.PickupRemarks,  
  CADS.DeliveryRemarks  
 INTO #ContactAddressDetails  
 FROM CR2.ContactAddress AS CA WITH (NOLOCK)  
 INNER JOIN #ContactGroupList list  
  ON list.ContactGroupId = CA.ContactGroupId  
 LEFT JOIN CR2.ContactAddressDefaultSettings AS CADS WITH (NOLOCK)  
  ON CADS.ContactAddressId = CA.ContactAddressId  
 LEFT JOIN CR2.ContactAddressDefault CAD WITH (NOLOCK) ON CAD.ContactAddressId = CA.ContactAddressId   
  AND CAD.UserId = @LoggedInUserId   
  AND CA.IsDeleted = 0  
  AND CA.AddressType IN (3)
```

This is my 1st table,

```
 SELECT 
     CA.ID  
    ,CA.CompanyName AS CompanyName   
    ,CA.ContactName AS ContactPerson         
    ,CA.Street  
    ,ISNULL(CA.Street2,'') AS Street2  
    ,CA.City  
    ,CA.[StateCode] AS [State]  
    ,CA.Country AS CountryCode
    , CASE  
        WHEN CA.Country = 1 THEN 'USA'  
        WHEN CA.Country = 2 THEN 'CANADA'  
        WHEN CA.Country = 4 THEN 'MEXICO'  
        END AS Country
    ,CA.ZipCode  
    ,CA.PhoneNo AS Phone  
    ,ISNULL(CA.Fax,'') AS Fax  
    ,CA.EmailId
    ,CA.AddressType   
    ,CA.AddressCode
    ,CA.PickupReadyTime AS  PickupReadyTime 
    ,CA.PickupCloseTime AS  PickupCloseTime   
    ,CA.DeliveryReadyTime AS DeliveryReadyTime  
    ,CA.DeliveryCloseTime AS DeliveryCloseTime 
    , CAST(ISNULL(CA.ID,0) as bit) IsDefault
    ,CA.PickupRemarks   
    ,CA.DeliveryRemarks      
    INTO #RexnordAddressDetails
  FROM [GTCommon].[dbo].[CustomerAddresses] AS CA WITH(NOLOCK)  
  WHERE CA.IsBlocked = 0  
   AND CA.AddressType IN (1,2) AND CA.CustomerId=@LoggedInUserId
```

This is my 2nd table
I am using Union to show both the table data. Is my approach right?

```
 SELECT *  
 FROM #ContactAddressDetails
 UNION 
 Select * 
 FROM  #RexnordAddressDetails
```

Please suggest

Comment: What's not working? You don't need to select into a tmp table for union

Comment: Same number of columns and matching data types for each columns? BTW, UNION ALL may be what you want. (UNION removes duplicate rows, UNION ALL keeps.)

Comment: I just wanted to know whether my approach is right or we have any other way than using unions?

Answer (score 0):

As @frlan says, you don't need to use the temp tables. You can do it all in one statement. Note that the column *names* of the output will be the column names defined in the first SELECT.

```
SELECT   
  CA.ContactAddressId,  
  CA.CompanyName AS CompanyName,  
  CA.ContactPerson AS ContactPerson,  
  CA.Address1 AS Street,  
  ISNULL(CA.Address2,'') AS Street2,  
  CA.City,  
  CA.[State] AS [State],  
  CA.Country AS CountryCode,  
  CASE  
   WHEN CA.Country = 1 THEN 'USA'  
   WHEN CA.Country = 2 THEN 'CANADA'  
   WHEN CA.Country = 4 THEN 'MEXICO'  
  END AS Country,  
  CA.ZipCode,  
  CA.WorkPhone AS Phone,  
  ISNULL(CA.Fax,'') AS Fax,  
  CA.Email AS [Email],  
  CA.AddressType,  
  CA.AddressCode,  
  CADS.PickupReadyTime AS PickupReadyTime,  
  CADS.PickupCloseTime AS PickupCloseTime,  
  CADS.DeliveryReadyTime AS DeliveryOpeningTime,  
  CADS.DeliveryCloseTime AS DeliveryClosingTime,  
  CAST(ISNULL(CAD.ContactAddressId,0) as bit) IsDefault,  
  CADS.PickupRemarks,  
  CADS.DeliveryRemarks  
 FROM CR2.ContactAddress AS CA WITH (NOLOCK)  
 INNER JOIN #ContactGroupList list  
  ON list.ContactGroupId = CA.ContactGroupId  
 LEFT JOIN CR2.ContactAddressDefaultSettings AS CADS WITH (NOLOCK)  
  ON CADS.ContactAddressId = CA.ContactAddressId  
 LEFT JOIN CR2.ContactAddressDefault CAD WITH (NOLOCK) ON CAD.ContactAddressId = CA.ContactAddressId   
  AND CAD.UserId = @LoggedInUserId   
  AND CA.IsDeleted = 0  
  AND CA.AddressType IN (3)  

UNION ALL

 SELECT 
     CA.ID  
    ,CA.CompanyName AS CompanyName   
    ,CA.ContactName AS ContactPerson         
    ,CA.Street  
    ,ISNULL(CA.Street2,'') AS Street2  
    ,CA.City  
    ,CA.[StateCode] AS [State]  
    ,CA.Country AS CountryCode
    , CASE  
        WHEN CA.Country = 1 THEN 'USA'  
        WHEN CA.Country = 2 THEN 'CANADA'  
        WHEN CA.Country = 4 THEN 'MEXICO'  
        END AS Country
    ,CA.ZipCode  
    ,CA.PhoneNo AS Phone  
    ,ISNULL(CA.Fax,'') AS Fax  
    ,CA.EmailId
    ,CA.AddressType   
    ,CA.AddressCode
    ,CA.PickupReadyTime AS  PickupReadyTime 
    ,CA.PickupCloseTime AS  PickupCloseTime   
    ,CA.DeliveryReadyTime AS DeliveryReadyTime  
    ,CA.DeliveryCloseTime AS DeliveryCloseTime 
    , CAST(ISNULL(CA.ID,0) as bit) IsDefault
    ,CA.PickupRemarks   
    ,CA.DeliveryRemarks      
  FROM [GTCommon].[dbo].[CustomerAddresses] AS CA WITH(NOLOCK)  
  WHERE CA.IsBlocked = 0  
   AND CA.AddressType IN (1,2) AND CA.CustomerId=@LoggedInUserId
```

I would advice against the (NOLOCK) hints unless you properly understand how they work.